# React component with ajax call - life-cycle

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, lifecycle

So I have an interesting case of using react with Ajax call.

To put it in the context, I have an accordion with 3 tabs. After initializing Accordion react component, I have the first tab initially open, the rest is closed. 
Every tab has in it's body so called DictionaryCall component which looks like this:

```
return class DictionaryCall extends React.Component {

        constructor (props) {
            super();
            this.state = {
                word: '',
                data: [],
                error: false,
                nodata: false,
                initialLoaded: props.load
            }
        }

        componentDidMount () {
            if(this.state.initialLoaded){
                this.callAjax();
            }
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
            if(nextProps.load){
                this.setState({initialLoaded: true});
                this.callAjax();
            }
        }

        callAjax () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.props.url,
                dataType: 'json',
                catche: false,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {word: this.props.word},
                success: function(data){
                    if(!data.length){
                        this.setState({nodata: true});
                    } else {
                        this.setState({data: data});
                    }
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    console.log(this.props.url, status, error.toString());
                    this.setState({error: true});
                }.bind(this)
            });
        }

        render () {
            let body,
                error = this.state.error;

            if(this.state.nodata){
                body = <div>No definition found</div>
            } else {
                body = <DataTab data={this.state.data} title={this.props.word}/>
            }

            return (
                <div className="dictionary-call">
                    {body}
                    {error ? <ServerError onClick={this.callAjax.bind(this)}/> : null}
                </div>
            )
        }
    };
```

Fist of all according to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) setting initial state with props is an anti-pattern, until you specify explicitly it's only  for component initialization.

So as it can be seen in the constructor, I'm setting `initialLoaded` state with `props.load`. I'm passing `props.load` as `true` only to the first Accordion tab as I want it to be loaded initially.

`componentDidMount` method is called and checks `initialLoaded` state. If it's set to `true` it simply calls ajax and re-render the component.

Now the tricky bit. The `componentWillReceiveProps` method. I'm expecting, the component will receive `nextProps.load` when user clicks on the Accordion tab to open it. Then `props.load` is passed to the component with `true` value.

My question is, is `componentWillReceiveProps` a good place to call `this.callAjax()` ? It seems a bit pointless to create the `initalLoaded` state in this case. Shouldn't I simply base on `props.load` instead and call `shouldComponentUpdate` ?

Or maybe I should stick with `initalLoaded` state and use `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`.

Bear in mind I want to call ajax call only once when the accordion tab gets opened for the first time.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you limited to using this architecture? I think this perpetuates the anti-pattern by making ajax calls inside your accordion component which sounds to me like it should only handle displaying data, not fetching anything. Wouldn't this be a lot easier by handling the fetching and accordion state higher up, even in your top level component?

Comment: Nope, I want each tab to fetch from different endpoint, additionally I want to trigger fetch based on `this.props.open` so only when user clicks a tab header. So it's completely fine to me.

Comment: I'm glad this works for you, but I implore you to consider a more 'React' way of handling this. In a flux style implementation, your components would not be making any ajax calls, that would all be handled in the actions layer. This allows your components to focus entirely on how things look, nicely decoupling behaviour and state.

Comment: Oh, in case of flux/redux, it would probably look different. I'm using React only as a view layer on top of Backbone.js

Comment: But you're mixing your view layer logic with business logic by making ajax calls inside UI components. Even with backbone, you want to do that stuff in top level components... I mean you can do it however, but if you were concerned with doing things the React way, and avoiding antipatterns..

Comment: Render method is dirty because it's just the first implementation of the component, later it will be moved into separate components, so this component will be responsible only for calling ajax and passing data to its children.

Answer (score 5):

So after a bit of research I want to answer my own question. Hope it helps someone.

The solutions is very simple and clean (in my opinion).

```
        componentDidMount () {
            if(this.state.initialLoaded){
                this.callAjax();
            }
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
            if(nextProps.load){
                this.setState({initialLoaded: true});
            }
        }

        componentWillUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
            if(this.state.initialLoaded !== nextState.initialLoaded) {
                this.callAjax();
            }
        }
```

This code applies to all instances of the component, no matter if it is a child of the first accordion tab (initially open) or the rest of tabs (initially closed).

In `componentDidMount` method, I'm checking if component should make an Ajax call. If during the initialization the `this.props.open` has set the `this.state.initialLoaded` state to true, than the ajax call is made. Otherwise of course not.

Now, when user clicks other tab, the component is expecting props in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Here I'm setting state only if `nextProps.load` is true, as I want to potentially load the data only if `load` field is true.

Lastly, if the condition in `componentWillReceiveProps` has been met, I'm checking if `this.state.initialLoaded` has changed. As it could be changed only when `nextProp.load` is true, it prevents from calling Ajax requests too many times (when state changes from true to false).

This way, I'm calling the Ajax request only when the tab is opened for the first time, or when it is initially opened.

That simple!